# Android : FATAL EXCEPTION AsyncTask #4

Tags: android, http, asynchronous

My application crash sometimes with this error :
It's a basically asynchronous http request to collect a picture on an url.

```
04-18 14:47:51.336: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10112): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4865)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:979)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4306)
    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10519)
    at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8635)
    at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:5647)
    at com.advertising.AdActivity.onPause(AdActivity.java:122)
    at com.advertising.AdActivity.close(AdActivity.java:355)
    at com.advertising.AdActivity.onImageFailure(AdActivity.java:470)
    at com.advertising.http.tasks.ImageHttpTask.raiseOnFailure(ImageHttpTask.java:74)
    at com.advertising.http.tasks.ImageHttpTask.doInBackground(ImageHttpTask.java:52)
    at com.advertising.http.tasks.ImageHttpTask.doInBackground(ImageHttpTask.java:20)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
    ... 4 more
```

And my DoInbackground :

```
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urldisplay);
        response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        raiseOnFailure(e, ErrorType.AD_ERROR);}
    return mIcon11;}
```

edit : this is my inPostExecute/raiseOnSuccess/raiseOnFailure :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    raiseOnSuccess(bmImage);
}

private void raiseOnSuccess(ImageView imageView) {
    if (this.imageHttpDelegate != null) {
        this.imageHttpDelegate.onImageSuccess(imageView);
    } else {
        Logger.d("Successfull image received.");
    }
}

private void raiseOnFailure(Throwable throwable, ErrorType errorType) {
    if (this.imageHttpDelegate != null) {
        this.imageHttpDelegate.onImageFailure(throwable, errorType);
    } else {
        if (throwable.getMessage() != null) {
            Logger.d(throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Can yout help me ? 
I don't say why she crash.

Comment: Are you manipulating view from doInBackground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `raiseOnFailure` method is accessing methods on your Activity that should only be called from the main thread. Try recording the error in your `AsyncTask` and then calling `raiseOnError` in the `onPostExecute` function.

### Example

```
private volatile Exception mError;
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urldisplay);
        response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mError  = e;
        return null;
    }
    return mIcon11;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(mError != null) { raiseOnFailure(mError, ErrorType.AD_ERROR); } 
        else {
           bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
           raiseOnSuccess(bmImage);
        }
     }
```

Comment: I don't know really what I do ? i add my other method in the post

Answer (score 0):

```
raiseOnFailure(e, ErrorType.AD_ERROR)
```

is acessing view from background

Answer (score 0):

you can not update UI directly from doinbackground() ,but you can do so in preexecute() or postexecute().

If its unavoidable to update UI from doinbackground() then you can do so in the following way :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                                       //update UI here

                        }

                    }
                });
```